# Calculating Percent Favorable

Tags: mysql

I have a table of survey responses that range from the following choices.
Strongly Agree = 5, Agree = 4, Neutral = 3, Disagree = 2, Strongly Disagree = 1

The table looks a bit like this:

```
ID:  Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Qn
1    5   4   5   3   2
2    4   5   2   1   4
3    4   4   3   2   3
4    5   4   3   4   3
```

I am using the following piece of MySQL code in order to take one column and generate 3 additional columns for percent favorable, neutral, and unfavorable.

```
Select 
(case when Q1 = 5 or Q1 = 4 then 1 else null end) as Q1Fav,
(case when Q1 = 3 then 1 else null end) as Q1Neu,
(case when Q1 = 2 or Q1 = 1 then 1 else null end) as Q1UnFav
From survey_data
```

This gives me favorable responses for Q1 in one column, neutral responses in another column, etc.

Is there a way to expand this to make MySQL continue to generate these columns until it's gotten to Qn? (where Qn is the last of the questions of the survey and the last column in my list).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- This should be all you need.

-- You can have 9 million surveys.

-- One can have 200 questions while another can have 4. Whatever.

```
create table users
(
    userId int auto_increment primary key,
    fName varchar(100) not null,    -- Stan 
    lName varchar(100) not null     -- Smith
)ENGINE=MyIsam;

create table surveys
(
    surveyId int auto_increment primary key,
    sTitle varchar(255) not null,
    dtCreated date not null -- date created in system
)ENGINE=MyIsam;

-- create table questions
-- (    -- to keep things simple to start, assume questions are not in mysql
    -- that can be for version Beta 0.02
-- );

create table UserTakesSurvey
(   -- A user takes a survey (this is going to be useful)
    -- 1 row for each combo kinda obvious
    userId int not null,
    surveyId int not null,
    dtTaken date not null,

    -- Foreign Key constraints go here:
    -- to Users Table:
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId),
    -- to Surveys Table:
    FOREIGN KEY (surveyId) REFERENCES surveys(surveyId),
    -- so no row can exist here with a wrong (non-existing) userId or surveyId

    -- addition indexes here:
    primary key (userid,surveyid),
    key (surveyid,userid)
)ENGINE=MyIsam;

create table answers
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    surveyId int not null, -- survey id
    qNum int not null,  -- question number
    answer int not null,    -- 5 to 1

    -- Foreign Key constraints go here:
    -- to Users Table:
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId),
    -- to Surveys Table:
    FOREIGN KEY (surveyId) REFERENCES surveys(surveyId),
    -- so no row can exist here with a wrong (non-existing) userId or surveyId

    -- Additional indexes go here:
    -- create a composite (combo) key incorporating two columns
    KEY (userId,surveyId),
    KEY (surveyId,userId)
)ENGINE=MyIsam;

insert users (fName,lName) values ('Stan','Smith'),('Sally','Higgins');

-- first survey will have 7 questions hypothetically, 2nd 101 questions
insert surveys (sTitle,dtCreated) values ('Feelings about Milk','2013-01-17');
insert surveys (sTitle,dtCreated) values ('Thoughts on Global Warming',curdate());
```

.

```
-- we now have 2 users, 2 surveys
-- Stan is id=1, Sally is id=2. Ditto for survey numbers starting at 1 and up.
-- in web loop, say PHP or whatever, you are collecting question answers
-- loop thru upon Final Submit and do your inserts into table 'answers' (one row each)

-- Assuming for now surveys themselves for simplicity exist on paper/webpage without questions embedded in database (which is not a problem).

-- But trying to simplify the example. Also note that answers.answer is not null but it can be null (no user answer).

-- One table contains all answers without the need to monkey around with creating columns as you were.
-- That monkeying around would be an answers table for each survey, bad idea.

-- This will perform very fast, and data is easily accessible as if in the format you desire. 
-- It may not be readily obvious how, but then again what are followup questions for :>
-- So that question is something like "How do I get at my data" !
```

Comment: Drew, thank you so much for your help.  I'm having a bit of trouble following your answer.  I'm a novice user of MySQL and I'd appreciate your help walking through this a bit.

Comment: No problem let me add more will take 15 minutes

Comment: Thank you.  If it helps and in case it wasn't clear, each record in the table I am working with represents a respondent to the survey, and the columns represent the survey questions themselves.

Comment: I know. I am presenting what I think is a much smarter design and will explain why. You can put it on a shelf and ponder it sometime

Comment: if these answers are helpful then upvote, if awful then downvote, and green checkmark answered so it is closed for you (and others know)

Comment: Thank you, Drew.  I followed your directions.  Thank you for the help!